# Arc4random не работает как должен

Tags: c, objective-c, случайные-числа

Как показывает гугление я не один столкнулся с этой проблемой:
[image]

в моем конкретном случае стояла задача сделать рандомным выпадение одной из двух карточек (симуляция выбора из двух игральных карт). При тестировании обнаружилось что одна карточка выпала 11 (!) раз подряд. При наличии выбора из трех карточек - одна из них выпала 6 раз подряд. Решил привязаться к миллисекундам времени нажатия клавиши выбора, и это в целом решило вопрос в более приемлемую сторону. Хочу поинтересоваться встречается ли данный вопрос у Вас (то есть не паранойя ли у меня) и если да то как с ним боретесь.

**UPDATE:**
читая man для arc4random встречаю строки: "...The arc4random() function returns
     **pseudo-random** numbers in the range of 0 to (2**32)-1, and therefore
     has twice the range of rand(3) and random(3). ..."
То есть все объяснимо, но не понял зачем тогда рандом который не является рандомным

Comment: Хм, периодически использую в отладочных целях для создания рандомных цветов для разных вьюх, проблем не замечал.

Comment: А как вы представляете себе получение _истинно_ случайного числа на полностью детерминистическом фон-Неймановском компьютере?

---
Вероятность того, что подряд выпадет 11 раз одна и та же карточка, равна 1/2^10 ~= 1/1000. Это — **огромная** вероятность, в любом приличном тесте (например, на 1000 простых пробегов) такое событие чрезвычайно вероятно.

А оправданы ли ваши требования к случайности?

Comment: Случай с двумя карточками конечно довольно сферичен, как и ситуация с тремя картами, но в сети вижу что у некоторых людей имеются по нескольку совпадений подряд в бОльших диапазонах. В моем случае меня попросили написать несколько простых форм для розыгрыша. Можете себе представить реакцию заказчика когда в розыгрыше несколько раз подряд выпало одно и то же значение, эффект рандомности был уничтожен и мне предъявлено некорректное поведение программы.

Comment: и что означает **pseudo**-random в описании функции?

Comment: Как правильно написал VladD, создание генератора случайных чисел попросту невозможно на современных вычислительных средствах. А потому было разработано множество математических алгоритмов по генерации чисел, чье значение создает впечатление случайности. 
На самом же деле тут все закономерно, берутся некоторые стартовые значения, изменяющиеся по определенным правилам, например время, и обрабатываются по определенному алгоритму (например вычисляются по формуле.) 
Как Вы понимаете, случайности здесь нет и быть попросту не может.

Comment: Таким образом я __убедил__ себя что использование альтернативы в виде отсчета от миллисекунд улучшило результат случайности?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет, это не паранойя, а общая болезнь многих генераторов. Ваше решение является одним из самых распространенных и в достаточной мере решает проблему. Если же нужно увеличить порядок случайности, то необходимо будет воспользоваться кастомным рандомом, алгоритмы в сети есть, но тут увеличатся накладные расходы.
Можете проверить С аналог, может результаты понравятся больше:

```
srand(time(NULL));
int m = rand();
```

Comment: спасибо за вариант, в следующий раз попробую его

Comment: Могу поспорить, что самописный рандом будет с _менее_ рандомным, чем рандом «из коробки». Потому что большинство авторов вариантов в интернете не читали 3-ю главу [TAOCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming). Разработчики больших библиотек обычно всё же более грамотны.

Comment: Конечно же имелись в виду именно математически-обоснованные алгоритмы. Выбирая кастомный алгоритм нужно смотреть для чего он нужен. Я бы посоветовал обратиться именно к алгоритмам, разработанным для криптографии. Они хоть и достаточно тяжелы, но дают прекрасные результаты.  
Примеры можно посмотреть на вики, а нормальную реализацию быстрее всего прийдется писать... 
Вся суть в том, для чего нужен этот генератор, какие требования к нему предъявляются.

Comment: @Dmitry Lepeshkin: В .NET есть встроенный [криптографический генератор случайных чисел](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx). Есть ли подобное в Objective C?

---
Всё же мне кажется, что проблема не в генераторе (использовать криптографический генератор для симуляции выбора двух карт в большинстве случаев перебор), думаю, ТС не очень близко знаком с теорией вероятности и [парадоксом дней рожденья](http://tinyurl.com/6dhxuv).

Comment: Мне тоже кажется, что в этих методах неи необходимости. Но решать тут автору. Быть может нам представлена ситуация в форме "сферического коня в вакууме", а на деле есть жесткие требования к случайности.

Comment: спасибо, коллеги. Безусловно вопрос необходимости таких мер это вопрос конкретного случая. Этим топом я пытаюсь прояснить а целом природу явления. Благодарю за ссылки, полезно было почитать

Comment: @AlexThumb: Посмотрите, может быть, вам пригодится [это](http://hashcode.ru/questions/181199).